# Dictionary to YAML dump preserving '\n\' and '\t' characters as strings rather than converting them?

Tags: python, json, dictionary, yaml, dump

I'm trying to update a YAML file by using a dictionary (yaml.load into dictionary, updated, and then dumped into a new file). However, during the process, special characters are converted to \n and \t, etc. and then preserved as text when dumped. Any idea on how to fix this?

```
import ruamel.yaml as yaml
import json

with open(file) as file:
    data = yaml.load(file, yaml.RoundTripLoader)
data = json.loads(json.dumps(data))

data.update(other_dict)

with open("file_new.yaml", "w") as file:
    yaml.dump(data, file, default_flow_style=False, Dumper=yaml.RoundTripDumper)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Example (dummy info)

```
data["description"] = "select\n    table_name.table_column\n\ from\n table_info info,\n person\n where id\
\ = person_thing\n"
```

It prints fine with it looking like when print(data["description"]) is run

```
select
     table_name.table_column
   from
      table_info info,
   where id = person_thing
```

However, when it dumps into a YAML file, it maintains the initial string

```
name: Ex
info:
    info: info
    info: info
description: "select\n    table_name.table_column\n\ from\n table_info info,\n person\n where id\
\ = person_thing\n"
```

where I'm expected it to be:

```
name: Ex
info:
    info: info
    info: info
description: 
    select
         table_name.table_column
       from
          table_info info,
       where id = person_thing
```

Comment: Can you please [edit] to show an expample where the result is incorrect? If you can produce one, you have found a bug; but I guess it's more likely that the output is correct, and you just need to understand what you are looking at.

Comment: I added an example - please let me know if more information is needed

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "it maintains the initial string". What does the resulting YAML look like, and what do you think it should look like instead?

Comment: I added in an expanded example - does that help?

Comment: There was another comment here which correctly remarked that the expected result isn't valid YAML, and pointed out the duplicate. Unfortunately, that comment is now gone.

Comment: (That's [this bug](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/384935/preserve-duplicate-nomination-comments-in-timeline), again.)